# Mac won't reboot or shutdown via GUI any more

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, reboot

A few weeks ago, I don't know exactly when but definitely with or after the upgrade from 10.9 to 10.11 my Late 2013 iMac stopped being able to reboot or shutdown via the GUI. When I click a reboot button in an installer or in Finder, it just crashes to the black kernel panic screen.

This makes OS X updates impossible. I had to update from 10.11.0 to 10.11.2 via a complete install of OS X from the recovery console.

I can reboot via the reboot or shutdown commands in Terminal. But any attempt to shutdown or reboot from the GUI generates a kernel panic.

Any ideas?

Update

This is what installing OS X via the recovery partition did:

[image: OS X version]

Comment: Either of your questions alone would invite speculative fix efforts… the two together suggest much deeper underlying problems [re http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214699/superdrive-doesnt-accept-disks-any-more ] - though mention of 10.11.2 is a disharmony, as it's not released yet…. Fully revert to a release would be the obvious first solution

Comment: 10.11.2 hasn't been released yet? So why did the recovery partition install it for me? Did the OS X install from the recovery partition send me into beta-land? Why? How would I revert? Note that the reason I installed OS X from the recovery partition was because I couldn't update to 10.11.1 because of the reboot issue.

Comment: Found a (German) discussion where someone says he (also) installed OS X via recovery partition and ended up with 10.11.2 (15C30) despite not participating in any beta programs. http://www.apfeltalk.de/magazin/2015/10/30/auch-os-x-10-11-2-als-public-beta-erschienen/

Comment: Simple answer would be "I have no clue" but it's definitely not released yet. [Sorry I can't do better than that]

Comment: Also: https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3qpfnz/why_did_this_happen/

Comment: Anyway, it has nothing to do with the problem, presumably. The reboot thing was already present before the upgrade to 10.11.2 (and was the reason why I even tried to upgrade).